# What this line does?

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

this is a piece of code from a register app which uses databases.Since i can say i know the basic principles of OOP , I understand this code **EXCEPT FOR THE FIRST LINE.** 
How can an object (reader) be a method(ExecuteReader()) of another object (cmd1) from another class(SqlCommand)?
I expected that the only way i can create an object is by writing sth like this: (class object = new class()).
A link where this to be explained would be welcomed too.

```
using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        reader.Close();
        if (textBox4.Text == textBox5.Text)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE info SET Password=@Password WHERE Id=@Id AND Password=@Password1", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox4.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", textBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password1", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Password has been changed");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("The new password doesn't match the one written in repeat the new password blank space ");
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Id or Password");
}
```

Comment: You know how methods can return a value, like an int or a string? They can return instances of objects, too. `ExecuteReader` returns an instance of a `SqlReader` object. the `using` block uses the object then once the block finishes it gets rid of the object.

Comment: Methods can return objects.  It would be pretty difficult to write an object oriented system if every return type had to be `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Here method call `cmd1.ExecuteReader()` returns an instance of object of type `SqlDataReader`.

Then reference to this object is being assigned to the variable `reader` of the same type `SqlDataReader`.

Answer (score 0):

`reader` is not a method, it is the object returned by the function `ExecuteReader`.

`ExecuteReader` will create an object with the usual syntax `new SqlDataReader(...)` and then return it. That's all !

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a greatly simplified version of that method doing something like this:

```
public SqlDataReader ExecuteReader() 
{
    return new SqlDataReader();
}
```

Obviously the implementation is more complex than this, but you can easily see how a method call can return you an object.